# Resultado incorrecto en consola

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en python con operadores de alto orden, que consiste en lo siguiente:

*Diseñe la función uno-verdadero, que recibe como entrada una lista de valores booleanos y devuelve True si al menos uno de los elementos de la lista es True.*

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
def unoVerdadero(lista):
    nuevaLista = reduce(lambda x,y: x and (not y) == False, lista)
    return nuevaLista

print(unoVerdadero([1,2,"True","False",False]))
print(unoVerdadero([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(unoVerdadero([False,False,False,False]))
print(unoVerdadero([True,True,True,True]))
```

Pero en consola, obtengo:

```
False
True
False
True
```

Cuando en realidad deberia ser:

```
False
False
False
True
```

Pense mil manera distintas de hacer el ejercicio, pero no lo consigo, alguien sabe cual es el error?

Comment: Cualquier valor numérico distinto de cero es `True`.

Comment: _"que recibe como entrada una lista de valores booleanos"_ ¿Por qué le estás pasando listas que tienen Strings y números? ¿No se supone que solo espere una lista en la que todos sus elementos sean booleanos?

Answer (score 1):

El detalle está en que `x` se considera `True` si es un valor distinto de cero, un string de largo mayor que cero, una lista con elementos, etc.

Una solución más sencilla:

```
def unoVerdadero(lista):
    return sum(x for x in lista if isinstance(x, bool)) > 0
```

La idea es recorrer la lista considerando sólo los valores tipo `bool` (descartando valores numéricos y strings):

```
x for x in lista if isinstance(x, bool)
```

En Python, `True` es 1 y `False` es 0. Con `sum()` estamos entonces contando la cantidad de `True` en la lista. Si es mayor que cero, entonces hay al menos un `True` presente.

**Edición**

Una solución usando operadores: lo apropiado sería usar `filter` para extraer de la lista todos aquellos elementos que son 1) de tipo `bool` y 2) `True`

```
filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool) and x, lista)
```

Esto va a producir una a) una lista vacía o b) una lista con uno o más `True`. Lo único que queda es retornar el valor de la comparación:

```
def unoVerdadero(lista):
    nuevaLista = [x for x in filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool) and x, lista)]
    return nuevaLista != []
```

Comment: Claro, entiendo tu comentario, pero el enunciado dice que hay que usar operadores de alto orden como map() filter() y/o reduce(), por lo tanto, por mas que el resultado es el correcto, no seria la forma correcta de realizar el ejercicio